# Solving polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, gap

I really love this website because you really exchange a lot of useful information. Let me tell you about my problem, I have these following equations:
$$ T_1=SZ^2+GX+C $$ 
$$ T_2=SY^2+GY+C $$
$$ T_3=S(Z+a)^2+G(X+a)+C$$
$$ T_4=S(Y+a)^2+G(Y+a)+C$$
$$Z=\frac{T_1-T_2}{T_4-T_2}*a+y$$
$$X=SZ^2+GZ+C$$
These are the known parameters: $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4,Y,a,Z$ and these are the unknown parameters:$X,S,G,C$ ...  I want to solve these 6 equations to find the X value without using (S,G,C).
Thanks for helping the science community.

Update:
I used GAP to solve this problem and i took the code from someone else in this website (sorry i forget his name) and this is his code after modifying it a little bit:

```
R := PolynomialRing( Rationals,["t1","t2","t3","t4","a","s","g","c","y","x","z"]);
AssignGeneratorVariables(R);
i1:=s*z^2+g*x+c-t1;
i2:=s*y^2+g*y+c-t2;
i3:=s*(z+a)^2+g*(x+a)+c-t3;
i4:=s*(y+a)^2+g*(y+a)+c-t4;
i5 := s*z^2+g*z+c-x;
I := Ideal(R, [i1,i2,i3,i4]);
ord := EliminationOrdering([s,g,c]);
B:=GroebnerBasis(I,ord);
```

GAP still in progress for more than an hour and i don't know if it will work or not.

Comment: You should tell us what are your thoughts on the problem, what you've tried and some context so we can better help you.

Comment: I'm trying now to use Gap to solve this problem and I'll attach my code here soon.

Comment: This is the code that i wrote in GAP(I took it from someone else in this website):R := PolynomialRing( Rationals, ["t1","t2","t3","t4","a","s","g","c","y","x",'z']);
too long i don't know how i can post it here and i'm still waiting for GAP to give me the answer (it's in the progress for a while)

Comment: @Faisal if you scroll down the page, there is a box in which you can add an answer. Note that you can also link the the question where you took it.

Answer (score 1):

The Gröbner basis functionality in GAP is implemented mainly for illustration purposes and is by far not as strong as dedicated systems. In particular elimination orderings perform far slower. If you try instead a lexicographic ordering, the calculation is much quicker:

```
gap> ReducedGroebnerBasis(I,MonomialLexOrdering([x,c,g,s,y,z,a,t1,t2,t3,t4]));
[ a*s*y-a*s*z-1/2*t1+1/2*t2+1/2*t3-1/2*t4, 
t1*a*s+2*t1*s*y-t2*a*s-2*t2*s*z-t3*a*s-2  ....
```

Now there is one polynomial that does not involve s,c,g. (We scale to make it look nicer):

```
gap> p:=Filtered(last,x->x=Value(x,[s,c,g],[0,0,0]));;
gap> 2*p[1];
t1*a*y+t1*a*x-2*t1*a*z-t1*y^2+2*t1*y*x-t1*z^2-t2*a*y-t2*a*x+2*t2*a*z-t2*y^2+2*t2*y*z-2*t2*x*z+t2*z^2+t3*a*y-\
t3*a*x+t3*y^2-2*t3*y*x+t3*z^2-t4*a*y+t4*a*x+t4*y^2-2*t4*y*z+2*t4*x*z-t4*z^2
```

This is linear in x, so get the coefficients and solve:

```
gap> co:=PolynomialCoefficientsOfPolynomial(2*p[1],x);;
```

and thus `-co[1]/co[2]` is the solution:

$x=\frac{-T_1ay+2T_1az+T_1y^{2}+T_1z^{2}+T_2ay-2T_2az+T_2y^{2}-2T_2yz-T_2z^{2}-T_3ay-T_3y^{2}-T_3z^{2}+T_4ay-T_4y^{2}+2T_4yz+T_4z^{2}}{T_1a+2T_1y-T_2a-2T_2z-T_3a-2T_3y+T_4a+2T_4z}$